# Google Calendar changing primary calendar events' time

Tags: google-calendar

On my primary calendar on Google Calendar, **any time I create an event, the event time gets moved to 3 hours prior to the time I specify**.  This does not happen immediately, but after a short time (e.g. an hour).

Things I have noticed:

- **All-day events get changed to 9:00pm - 9:30pm the day prior.**
- **All non-all-day events simply have their start and end time shifted back 3 hours.**
- **This only happens to events on the PRIMARY calendar** (I know of no way to delete the calendar entirely, or to change the primary calendar).

I have gone through all settings related to my Google account, Google Calendar, and the specific calendar, and verified that **all timezones are set properly to "Arizona" time** (no daylight savings, currently GMT-7:00 Mountain Time.  **I have no devices set up to sync with the calendar** (I simply access from https://www.google.com/calendar/render).

In addition, **I have deleted all events on the calendar**, and there are no events that are shared by any of my calendars (though I have set up 3 "Interesting" calendars -- Weather, US Holidays, Friends' Birthdays).

My current resolution to this issue is to rename the calendar to 'DO NOT USE', but given that this is the primary calendar (default for all events, unhidable, and at the top of the list), it is rather annoying.

My question is **how can I resolve this problem?**  I am looking for an answer that will tell me any of the following:

- **How can I change the primary calendar?**
- **How can I delete the primary calendar?**
- **How can I resolve the time-changing issues with the calendar?**

Comment: Timezone changes are causing it. You have one timezone set on your calendar, and whatever you're syncing with thinks it's another timezone, probably GMT.

Comment: There are timezones on events as well. Have you checked those? http://cl.ly/1s0y2x2i1E2n161J2n2m

Comment: My phone is out of the equation, since it's been happening since before I had it.  I have not synced with any other device, and all computers I've used have the correct timezone.  @Dez Without making it all day, events default to the right timezone.  Choosing all-day for an event removes the time zone option.

Comment: Are you sure that you have set the same time zone in your Google Account, Google Calender Settings, The particualr Google Calender in Question, the particualr event in question, your mobile phone?

Comment: @RishabhPoddar Google Account -- I don't see any settings for this.  [Google Calendar Settings](http://i.imgur.com/SgIlK.png).  [The Particular Google Calendar](http://i.imgur.com/qpNxj.png). The Particular Event -- All day events have no time zone (but the specified time-zone before changing to all-day is correct).  Your Mobile Phone -- Yes, I double checked this the other day.  From what I can tell, all time-zone settings are correct (updated question to indicate this)

Comment: There are [time zone settings for the important Google services involved](https://www.google.com/settings/products?hl=en), especially [Calendar](https://www.google.com/calendar/render?settings=0&authuser=0), [Docs](http://docs.google.com/settings?authuser=0) and [Gmail](http://mail.google.com/mail/?authuser=0#settings). You can hover over each service to see a link to the Settings. You didn't mention that your Windows XP/7 Time Zones are correct. Also, can you say where you're entering the events (via web interface to Google Calendar, etc.)?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator I looked in Gmail but I don't see any time-zone settings.  I've already said Calendar's settings are accurate, and I will check my Docs and other account settings when I have access.  All computers I use have the proper time-zone settings, updated the question to more explicitly state this.

Comment: Gmail settings are part of user settings in Google (it takes some clicking). This should be shorter: https://www.google.com/settings/?hl=en then click Edit under the Email addresses and usernames (Primary email).

Comment: @Fuhrmanator My [Gmail/Google Account time-zone](http://i.imgur.com/RkGkM.png) also seems to be correct already.  I've never moved nor changed my time-zone, so anything being incorrect (unless it was an incorrect default) would be strange.

Comment: Have you found a solution in the meantime?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I haven't had any luck, my current solution is renaming the main calendar to 'DO NOT USE', so I have to change the calendar for all quick add events.

Comment: Are you _absolutely_ sure you are not syncing with anything? Like iCal on your Mac, or other desktop calendar software? If not, I would file a support ticket with Google for this, as it is certainly not right.

Answer (score 1):

It's a time zone conflict between your Google Calendar and the devices you sync it with. I had the same problem. One of my devices didn't have Daylight Savings set, and after syncing it would send a different time back to the Google servers.